# Tabs not showing up using tabhost

Tags: android

this is my code to show three tabs on top of screen,
but its not showing any tabs on the screen,and i don't have the slightest clue why this is happening,can somebody please guide me
here is the XML

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and here is the java code

```
final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
final TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
final TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
final TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third Tab");
tab1.setIndicator("Upcoming").setContent(new Intent(this, Upcoming_matches.class));
tab2.setIndicator("Recent").setContent(new Intent(this, Recent_matches.class));
tab3.setIndicator("Fixture").setContent(new Intent(this, Fixtures.class));
tabHost.addTab(tab1);
tabHost.addTab(tab2);
tabHost.addTab(tab3);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) Math.ceil((width / 1)), 60));
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) Math.ceil((width / 3)), 60));
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) Math.ceil((width / 3)), 60));
```

Found the answer ,with the help of @Don,it was basically wrong layout,framelayout was below than tabwidget,here is correct XML

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="78dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Comment: Have you defined the activities in your manifest?

Comment: yes,its part of main activity,other components are working as they should,except this,if you want full code ,i can post it here

Comment: TabHost has been deprecated for years. Use TabLayout instead.

Comment: You should consider using a not-deprecated solution (`TabActivity` is deprecated for a reason), use [TabLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change fill_parent to wrap_content in tabconent 
here is the xml

```
     <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="78dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: thanx @Don, nearly solved it
now its showing in android studio but not on device,guide further please