# Can it is possible to use tabhost in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to use `TabHost` in `MainActivity` it is crashing. No idea where is the problem. In the java file in 31th line it is showing error. Previously I'd separately written the `TabHost` section from `MainActivity` and added `TabHost` using "include" syntax. But the project was showing nothing on screen. So, i joined them in `MainActivity`.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
        TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
        TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");

        tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

        tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
        tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

        tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
        tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#caceca"
    tools:context="com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app.MainActivity">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

           <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
           </TabWidget>

           <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
           </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

After few changes like collapsible toolbar, it is not showing the tabs...

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/list1">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                     android:id="@+id/tab2"
                     android:orientation="vertical"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:id="@+id/list2">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/list3">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app;

import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new   LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    }
}
```

In the tabs it will show the video thumbnails in cardview.

Comment: post the error log..

Comment: error log - "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Comment: this is not the error log....try getting the log in Android studio when crash occur...`Error Log will appear in red color`

Comment: error log - "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app/com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)"

Comment: i have added the answer..check it below

Comment: search on google for tabhost example. You will get better help for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your Activity:

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
   }
```

Comment: change framelayout: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` see this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994077/tabs-not-showing-up-using-tabhost)

Comment: I added collapsible toolbar. After that, there is problem

Comment: it  would be better if you ask a new question with code and screenshot...so that everybody can help...the context of this question is already answered